# The specified child already has a parent, creating recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Could some one help me I don't know why I get this error.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                   Process: com.sangra.igurdwara, PID: 24038
>                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4659)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4495)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4436)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:676)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:7399)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7357)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7345)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1459)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:580)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3374)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3183)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3627)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17993)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
>                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
>                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1731)
>                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1496)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17993)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
>                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
>                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17993)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17993)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
>                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
>                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17993)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
>                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
>                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17993)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
>                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
>                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3172)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17993)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2759)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2460)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1528)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7524)
>                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
>                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
>                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:622)
>                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

```
public class TenantAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TenantAdapter.TenantViewHolder> {

    private List<Tenant> values;
    private final OnItemClickListener listener;

    public TenantAdapter (List<Tenant> values, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.values = values;
    this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(Tenant tenant);
    }


    static class TenantViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView nameTextView;

    TenantViewHolder(TextView itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nameTextView = itemView;
    }

    void bind(final Tenant tenant, final OnItemClickListener listener){
        nameTextView.setText(tenant.getName());
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onItemClick(tenant);
            }
        });
    }
    }


    @Override
    public TenantViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_tenant, parent, false);
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_tenant_name);
    TenantViewHolder tenantViewHolder = new TenantViewHolder(nameTextView);
    return tenantViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TenantViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(values.get(position), listener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
    return values.size();
    }

}

public class TenantActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tenant);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.activity_tenant_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    List<Tenant> values = new ArrayList<>();
    Tenant temp = new Tenant();
    temp.setName("Gurdwara Guru Nanak Mission Sewa Society");
    values.add(temp);
    adapter = new TenantAdapter(values, new TenantAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Tenant tenant) {
            TenantActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(TenantActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the child TextView in the constructor of the ViewHolder which is not right. You should pass the parent view and unwrap it in the constructor instead.

```
static class TenantViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView nameTextView;

    TenantViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_tenant_name);
    }
}
```

and in Your Adapter just pass the inflated view directly.

```
@Override
public TenantViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_tenant, parent, false);
    TenantViewHolder tenantViewHolder = new TenantViewHolder(rowView);
    return tenantViewHolder;
}
```